# How to enable repository and install libinput on VMWare with openSUSE Leap 15.2

Tags: qt, repository, rfid, opensuse

First of all, I want to clarify that I am a complete noob concerning `Linux/openSuse/etc`. I am working on a project in `QTCreator` which will use a **RFID** Reader, to get the data of this reader I want to use the library "libinput" since the reader sends this data as if it is a keyboard. My problem is now that I need to install this library first. I found a website explaining the steps on how to this but I am already unsure what the first step means. The websites provide two links to repositories of libinput and state the I should follow the instruction of these repositories but I am unable to figure out where the instruction is or what the instructions are.

Here is the guide I am following: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building.html#building-against

I am using a VMWare running openSUSE Leap 15.2 and the project will run on an embedded Linux system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libinput is available at OpenSUSE repository [link](https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.2/repo/oss/)

Steps to install it on OpenSUSE platform

```
zypper ar -f https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.2/repo/oss/ 15.2-Current-oss
zypper refresh 15.2-Current-oss
zypper in libinput-devel
```

In order to query some package in the configured repositories you can use `zypper se <name>`